# How can I fix my C++ program? The program is supposed to get the number of spaces in a string with a function

Tags: c++, input

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/**
   Gets the number of spaces in a string.
   @param str any string
   @return the number of spaces in str
*/

string count_spaces(string hi) {
   int spaces;
   for (int i = 0; i < hi.length(); i++) {
      if (hi.substr(i, 1) == " ")
          spaces +=1;
   }
   return spaces;
}

int main()
{
   string str;
   getline(cin, str);
   cout << count_spaces(str) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error in my C++ program. `spaces` is an `int` value in the program.

```
Error: helper_function.cpp: In function ‘std::string count_spaces(std::string)’:
helper_function.cpp:17:8: error: could not convert ‘spaces’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
   17 | return spaces;
      |        ^~~~~~
      |        |
      |        int
```

I'm not sure how to go about solving it.

Comment: The function `count_spaces` is returning string

Comment: Please put more thought into your question title. *"How can I fix my C++ program?"* could easily fit the list of vague (hence bad) question titles in [ask]. Mentioning the purpose your your program (instead of mentioning the kind of error) would also go under "bad title".

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
int count_spaces(string hi)
```

instead of

```
string count_spaces(string hi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count_spaces()` function is declared to return a `string` instead of an `int`. You need to fix that:

```
int count_spaces(string hi)
```

Also, you need to initialize `spaces`, otherwise the code has *undefined behavior* when `hi` is empty since it will be returning an *indeterminate* value:

```
int spaces = 0;
```

Also, `if (hi.substr(i, 1) == " ")` can be simplified to `if (hi[i] == ' ')`, and `spaces +=1;` simplified to `++spaces;`.

Although, you should consider using the standard [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm instead of counting characters manually:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

size_t count_spaces(string hi) {
   return count(hi.begin(), hi.end(), ' ');
}
```